# error with basic java code

Tags: java, compiler-errors, inputstream, outputstream

This is some basic java code:

```
package javaapplication32;

import java.io.*;

public class JavaApplication32 {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        try{
            out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dec.dat")));
            in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("enc.dat")));

            String enc=in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(enc);
        }catch(EOFException e){
        }
    }   
}
```

I am getting the error that it cannot find the symbol 'in' or 'out'

Comment: How about declaring the variables before using them?

Comment: You havent declared out or in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should declare them first.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    DataOutputStream out = null; 
    DataInputStream in = null;
    try{
        out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dec.dat")));
        in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("enc.dat")));

        String enc=in.readUTF();
        System.out.println(enc);
    }catch(EOFException e){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to define variables you must give them types, e.g.:

```
OutpustStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dec.dat")));
InputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("enc.dat")));
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not actually declared anything as `in` or `out`.

`DataInputStream in =`

`DataOutputStream out =`

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
package javaapplication32;
import java.io.*;

public class JavaApplication32 {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dec.dat")));
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("enc.dat")));

            String enc=in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(enc);
        } catch(EOFException e) {
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare in and out as something first!

DataInputStream in =

DataOutputStream out =

**E.g.**

```
out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dec.dat")));
    in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("enc.dat")));
```

Answer (score -3):

In Java, Pre Initialisation of strings is mandatory. Only then you can use them inside a program. Easiest way to do this is:

```
String in="";
String out="";
```

You should be fine...

Comment: Sorry, this is plain nonsense. in and out aren't Strings, they are Input/Output streams. And it is not about *initialisation*, but about *declaration*. Your answer adds nothing new. And worse: it only adds **wrong** information.